# Using css in converted svg to img

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

I am trying to convert an svg to an image format. Actually a lot works very fine and I know how to convert from SVG to canvas and from canvas to img. My problem is that the svg uses css that has been included as css file and by converting to canvas, the styles will be lost.

Does anyone has an idea how to copy the styles into my svg or canvas?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/DaWa/70w9db1d/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>SVG2IMG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./circle.css">
</head>
<body>
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg>

<script>
  var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

  let xml  = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  let data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(xml);
  let img  = new Image();
  img.src  = data;
  document.body.appendChild(img)

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
circle {
    fill:red
}
```

Comment: @JGFMK That linked page does not help with the OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this trick to add computed style of each node to its style attribute, and it works. may be it can help you.

**Update 1:** some browsers do not support the cssText property so you can use the code below which is a bit more cross browser.

**Update 2:** Firefox computes css quotes property which include some invalid string chars that btoa can not encode properly.

```js
let addStyle = function(children) {
   for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
     let child = children[i];
     if (child instanceof Element) {
       let cssText = '';
       let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(child, null);
       for (let i = 0; i < computedStyle.length; i++) {
         let prop = computedStyle[i];
         cssText += prop + ':' + computedStyle.getPropertyValue(prop) + ';';
       }
       child.setAttribute('style', cssText);
       addStyle(child.childNodes);
     }
   }
 }

 let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
 addStyle(svg.childNodes);
 let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
 let data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(xml)));
 let img = new Image();
 img.src = data;
 document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
circle {
  fill: red
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There's some cross-browser issue here. The image is black in my main browser (Firefox/54.0.1 on Win64) and red in Chrome. (Edge crashes on "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'" but I guess that's an entirely different issue.) Nice approach anyway.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes computedStyle works on web-kit only I guess. I'll add this to the answer. thanks for reminding.

Comment: Yet [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=getComputedStyle) shows quite a broad support. Perhaps it's just not working on SVG.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález apparently other browsers do not support cssText. in IE it return empty string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and the fast update, but it still seems not to work for example on firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking in Firefox Developer Edition on a Mac (which doesn't work), and comparing it to Chrome/Safari (which does work), if you copy the link address after inspecting the inserted second svg, Firefox has a much shorter link (40 times less) svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIj4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI1MCIgY3k9IjUwIiByPSI0MCIgc3R5bGU9IiIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=

Comment: I debugged it in Firefox Developer Edition and the style has no value. So for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe Firefox doesn't like recursive calls?

Comment: @user7521838 I fixed the issue with firefox and made sure it works with Chrome, IE and firefox. let me know if you have problems with other browsers

Comment: @JGFMK the problem with firefox is that you can't set properties of style object like I have done. so I needed to convert the computed style to a string and add it to style attr and there was also the problem of encoding for some css properties that firefox computes, for example qoutes, they include some characters which btoa does not support normally

Comment: @NimaHakimi Thank you very much. That seems to work for all browsers I need.